# How to Resume a windowless app (LSUIElement) in OS X Lion

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

In OS X Lion apps automatically resume when the user logs in. My app is set to be a windowless agent without an icon in the Dock (`LSUIElement` is set to `YES` in `Info.plist`) and it doesn't resume when I restart my machine.

According to [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CommonAppBehaviors/CommonAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH7-SW3) all applications get the Resume behaviour by default and the developer doesn't need to do anything special to enable it. Are `LSUIElement` apps a special case? Is there anything that needs to be done to enable them to Resume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my own testing, `LSUIElement` applications are not resumed. So yes, they appear to be a special case – you'd need to ask Apple why this is the case, but setting this value appears to forcibly disable resume.

Comment: Did you try sending the enableRelaunchOnLogin message (to decrement the counter) per the documentation you linked?